# retrieve best cutoff of ROCR and compare?

Tags: roc, model-comparison

I am new to ROCR curves and I wanted to use them to evaluate some methods:

I am using the same code as in ‘introduction to statistical learning’, that is:

```
> library (ROCR)
> rocplot =function (pred , truth , ...){
+ predob = prediction (pred , truth )
+ perf = performance (predob , "tpr ", "fpr ")
+ plot(perf ,...)}
```

The resulting curves:

[image]

I do understand that the blue one shall be the best method because it has the largest area under the curve.

My question is: I want to do a confusion matrix, how do I retrieve the cutoff value that gives me the best predictions?

My subsequent question is, the cutoff value that gives me the best predictions for the blue, might not be the same value that gives them for the black one, right? In that case is it ok to retrieve the best cutoff for each and compare the methods using different cutoffs?

Comment: You need a mechanism of judging "best", probably in terms of the relative costs and propensities of false positives and false negatives

Comment: Let's say FP and FN 'cost' the same... How can I retrieve the best?

Comment: If you are trying to minimise $FP+FN$ then you want the cutoff corresponding to the point of the curve which touches (but does not cross) a straight line with slope $\frac{N}{P}$, which is why propensity matters.  And if you have multiple curves, you want the one which in this sense gives a straight line closest to the to left-corner.  The optimal cuttoff may indeed differ between the curves